# Fill Matrix Rows in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, nested-lists

Let's say we have a nested list in Python. AKA a matrix, and we have a list consisting of elements, lets say li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. I want to insert two elements in matrix rows, resulting matrix = [ [1,2] [3,4], [5,6] ]. How can this be done ? Thanks!

```
b = [[]]
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(len(c)):
    for j in range(2):
        b[i].append(c[i])

print(b)
```

Comment: This code will crash on the second iteration of the outer loop, as there is no `b[1]`.

Comment: You need to add sub-lists directly to `b` , i.e. `b.append([])`

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be done ?

- split the list with slices
  `a[0:2],a[2:4],a[4:6]`
- append each of those to an empty list
- or construct a list with those slices as the items

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just like this:

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = []
fixed_c = []
for i in range(len(c) + 1):
    if len(b) < 2 :
        b.append(c[i])
    elif len(b) == 2 and i != len(c):
        fixed_c.append(b)
        b = []
        b.append(c[i])
    else:
        fixed_c.append(b)
        
print(fixed_c)
```